# Return reference from function vs binding temporary to const ref

Tags: c++, reference, return-type

Am I right, that this (taken from [this GotW](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)):

```
string f() { return "abc"; }

void g() {
    const string& s = f();
    cout << s << endl;    // can we still use the "temporary" object?
}
```

is completely fine, while this is not ok at all:

```
const string& foo() { string x{"abc"}; return x; }
void bar() {
    const string& y = foo();
}
```

?

Why is it different? Can one say that "the lifetime of a temporay is not extended across a function call (even if bound to a const ref)" ?
Or what is an explanation, why the first is ok, but not the second?

Comment: First answer there answers your questions.

Comment: @GillBates yep I also just found it

Answer (score 2):

The 1st one is pretty fine, because the returned value (which is a temporary) is bound to a reference to const directly, then the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the reference's lifetime.

Note that there's no temporary in the 2nd case, `x` is a local variable which will be destroyed when get out of the function, then the function will always returns a dangled reference; that reference is used to initialize `y` but nothing changes, `y` will be a dangled reference too.